# ¿Como puedo concatenar bits en c++?

Tags: c++

Necesito saber cómo puedo concatenar bits en c++, ayuda pls, he buscado en internet pero solo me sale para cifras o textos pero yo necesito específicamente bits y no me sale

Comment: ¿[Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102517/concatenating-bits-in-c) te sirve?

Comment: Cómo o para qué lo quieres? Podrías hacer un arreglo de `bool` pero no de bits, ya que la memoria se accede por bytes.

Comment: Creo que te refieres al uso de operaciones de bit (bitwise), pero deberías poner algún ejemplo de a que te refieres, porque no queda claro.